# How can I refresh my table content from the child component in the parent component with click event?

Tags: angular, typescript, event-binding

I have created a table in the child component and also stored a refresh function in it. Now I would like to call this in my parent component and execute it by clicking on the button. Can you please tell me how I can realize this?

My Code:

```
// Child-Component

ngOnInit() {
this.refresh();
}

  /**
   * Refresh Data Table
   */
  public refresh() {
    if (!this.isLoading) {
      this.all = false;
      this.clearRows();
      this.loadData();
    }
  }

  public clearRows() {
    const formArray = this.salesAreaForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    formArray.clear();
  }
```

```
// Parent-Component

<button>Refresh Child-Component</button>
<app-child-component></app-child-component>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) in the parent component.

```
import { ..., ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;

...
childComponent.refresh();
...
```

Comment: Is there also a possibility to refresh several ChildComponents at once? I have tried it with three components, the first is updated and the other two output errors. Do you know the problem?

Comment: You can try ViewChildren. You can get the list of ChildComponents with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get the child component as a viewchild and simply call the method directly on the component.

```js
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;

  onClick() {
      childComponent.Refresh()
  }
```

I would normally prefer using a service for this though

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. **Shared Service**
   You can add the shared service for communication between parent and child component. It will allow the bidirectional communication as well. You can find the detailed info [on the Angular site](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).
2. **@ViewChild**
   In your parent class add the following:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child:ChildComponent; 
onRefreshClick(){ 
    this.child.refresh() 
}
```

You will get an access to your child properties and method by using the `ViewChild` decorator. Then add a on-click handler to your button and call the `refresh` method in your child.

The detailed description you can find [on the Angular site](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild).

3. **State Management**

You can add the store to your app and listen for the events in the store. This is the preferable way, but its a good way for a middle-to-large apps.